# how we can change the color of icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the icon color.
not back-ground color.
my html code:

```
<i class="icon-large icon-3x icon-arrow-up go-top" style="color:#eee;"></i>
```

css:

```
.go-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;

    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 1em;
}

i.go-top:hover{
border-color:red;}
```

change the color of icon on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing border color.

To change color use `color:`

```
i.go-top:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3.0 or the older version?

Comment: bootstrap 3.0 and older both